# Google Places API opening hours last updated at

Tags: google-places-api

While searching on Google, sometimes I see "Updated by business 6 days ago" underneath the opening hours. How can I get this timestamp via the API?

Comment: If I understand correctly, you can sometimes see that when using maps.google.com and not on the Places API itself. If so, since they are different entities, it doesn't mean that it is available on one doesn't mean it is available on the other. And by checking their [Place data fields](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/place-data-fields) they provide, they don't actually have this feature on the Maps API. So the best course of action you can take for now is to file a feature request by following: https://developers.google.com/issue-tracker/

Comment: I was afraid of that. Given everything is available through their API, I would have expected to be able to fetch this information as well.